# construct lablel id from variables

Tags: c#, .net

I have a lot of labels/button on my form, they are named like lable_1, label_2, label_3.

I have a loop that sets the labels/buttons properties. Is there a way to construct the name of the label from a variable.

Example:

```
while()
{

int++;
label_1.Text="abc";    <---- Something like label_+'int'.Text="abc"

}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your `Label` controls have the same parent, you can use the [FindControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) method of their parent in order to fetch them from their ids:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= yourLabelCount; ++i) {
    Label label = labelParentControl.FindControl(String.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "label_{0}", i)) as Label;
    if (label != null) {
        label.Text = "abc";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. There is no [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) keyword like in PHP.

The better is to define a list of labels and then use the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx) property for that:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<Label> labels = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Label>();

int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    Label newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.Name = string.Format("label_{0}", i++);

    labels.Add(newLabel);
}
```

Another way is to use a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead:

```
System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary<string, Label> labels = new System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary<string, Label>();

int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    Label newLabel = new Label();
    string name = string.Format("label_{0}", i++);

    labels.Add(name, newLabel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you try to do that, i think it is so bad idea,because after a period of time you will be no more able to distinguish between those controls .. so the best advice is to use naming conventions to identify those controls easily,and give them names even if they are many.. still you can construct your controls names through a loop .

Answer (score 0):

lable_1 , label_2 are not good names for a control , try to give some meaning ful names.

for answer your query

yes , you can acheive

```
int i = 1;

while(some terminating condition)
{

 var lbl = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(x=>x.Name==label_+ i.ToString()).ToList()[0];

 lbl.Text ="abc";

 i++ ;
}
```

Comment: My lnks and buttons are meaning full, but considering that there will be around 50 of each, it will require repetitive work.           Saurabh, From your last solution does there have to be a parent lable? I tried your solution it seems not working for me.   Thanks everyone,